# Unsupported model type: TENSORFLOW when trying to add tensorflow model to BigQuery ML

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to follow this guide:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-batch-predictions-of-tensorflow-models-directly-in-bigquery-ffa843ebdba6

in order to create a BQML model from an exported tensorflow model.

When running the `CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL` command, I hit the following error message:

> Unsupported model type: TENSORFLOW

I have also tried to create a BQML model from the exported tensorflow model used in that example with the exact command suggested there:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL advdata.txtclass_tf
OPTIONS (model_type='tensorflow',
         model_path='gs://cloud-training-demos/txtclass/export/exporter/1549825580/*')
```

with the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in public alpha. Contact your GCP sales rep to get whitelisted

Comment: Thats what I was missing!! If only it was on that medium article in italics or something so it stood out.... oh wait.... :-) Thanks Lak (and apologies for missing that clear note on your original article!)